# How do I create an installer package for mono built on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi model B that I just bought. I downloaded and built the complete Mono source code to try to solve the hard float issue because supposedly a developer just committed a fix in the 3.2.7 version.

I have done the build and it worked without errors. I would now like to create a package or tarball or something that I can use to take what I just built and install it on other RPi devices.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Something like this: configure --prefix=/opt/mono-3.2.7 && make && make install && tar -cjf ~/mono-3.2.7.tar.bz2 /opt/mono-3.2.7 (of course, if you're cross-building or building in qemu, it will be a bit more complicated)

Comment: I am building on the RPi. When I did the build my prefix was /usr/local. Does that make a difference? If I have already run make and make install can I just do the tar?

Comment: There will be a lot of unrelated stuff in /usr/local, it is not generally a good idea to install anything there circumventing the package manager. Does not look like mono supports installing anywhere other than configure-time prefix.

Comment: Bummer. The mono project docs tell you to use that prefix when building. Wish I would have known. I takes about 20 hours to build it and I would rather not build again.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to extract just what I need for an install onto other devices now that I already have it in /usr/local?

Comment: You can try to discriminate mono-installed files by their time stamps. Or you can use something like http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/

Comment: Thanks. I will give something like that a try.

Comment: Btw., you don't need to spend 20 hours re-building mono. You can cross-build mono in a usermode qemu environment.